# Finding optical properties (epsilon) by Quantum ESPRESSO

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, ab-initio-calculations

I am calculating the dielectric (Epsilon) for ZnO by quantum espresso, when I run the eps.in file, I always get this error. `Reading namelist energy_grid'`
How do I solve this problem?

My eps.in:

```
&INPUTPP
calculation = 'eps',
outdir = './' /
&ENERGY_GRID 
smeartype = 'gauss',
intersmear = 0.1500,
intrasmear = 0.000,
wmax = 10.000,
wmin = 0.000,
nw = 600,
shift = 0.010,
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever there is an error saying `Reading namelist *******`, that means there is something wrong with the input file, almost always it is a syntax mistake.

I think here you didn't close the namelist with a `/` properly. I am not sure about the soundness of your input parameters, but a correct way to write the same input file would look like:

```
&INPUTPP
calculation = 'eps'
outdir      = './'
/
&ENERGY_GRID 
smeartype  = 'gauss'
intersmear = 0.1500
intrasmear = 0.000
wmax       = 10.000
wmin       = 0.000
nw         = 600
shift      = 0.010
/
```

This should work.